# MegaEXO Omega BB and Hollowtech II crank compatibility?

Tags: bottom-bracket, crankset

I have a Giant TCX SLR 2 (2014) with a FSA MegaEXO BB and FSA Omega crankset (46/36).

I just purchased a Ultegra 6750 crankset (50/34), can I run it on my existing BB?

If not, what BB do I need?

I have read online that it should work as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the Omega MegaEXO FSA system uses a 19mm spindle diameter and hollowtech II is 24mm.

FSA BB86 BB (For alloy cranksets) or Shimano BB91 Road Press Fit Bottom Bracket will work.